# get notified when another page updates

Tags: php, ajax

I can lock and unlock certain questions.
Let's say I do this with foo.php

On bar.php I would like to check every second if something is unlocked with foo.php.
What is the best way to do this?

I'm thinking of a ajax request every second to a checkUnlock.php. But i'm not sure what checkUnlock.php should return.

Comment: Do you truly need second-level accuracy here? There's no such thing as "an average data limit".

Comment: I probably have around 250gb data limit a month. Since that being the basic host packet of my hosting those days. Could be less when i signed but probably not that less :)

Comment: Whenever someone says "ajax request every second" the first thing that comes to my mind is [socket communication](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php)... Although if you do decide to look deeper into sockets I would recommend looking at alternative to PHP for the actual socket server.

Comment: Never heard of it. I will look into it. Thx